# Boost enable_if in constructor

Tags: c++, boost, enable-if

I have a templated class, and I want to enable a certain constructor only when the type is a double.  What's wrong with this code?

```
template<typename T>
class B: public A<T>
{
public:
    B(int arg1=0, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_same<T, double>::value>=0);
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
B<double> B( 6, 6 );
}
```

I'm getting the error: "default argument for parameter of type ‘boost::enable_if_c’ has type ‘int’" but I'm not sure what is meant by this.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Looks like a missing `::type`

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What you coded is 'B can be instantiated only if T is double'. But what the use of `template` then? SFIANE does not work in this case, because `T` is class parameter, not function one.

Comment: I have more than one constructor, but I only want a certain constructor to only be available for B<double>.

Comment: When I put:

B(int arg1=0, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_same<T,double>::value,int>::type arg2=0);

I get the error:
no type named "type" in "struct boost::enable_if_c<false, int>"

Comment: @user1504193: That's because you can't use this for SFINAE. You can use this concept to limit your class template to doubles only, but then why bother with a template? What might make more sense template-wise would be to limit your template to floating point types only by changing that `boost::is_same<T,double>` to `boost::is_floating_point<T>`.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you can't really do that. If you provide some `T` which is not `double`, then the compiler will try to resolve `enable_if_c<false>::type`, which will fail, making the whole class instantiation fail, not just the constructor.

You can use C++11's default function template arguments to achieve the same.

The code below implements that using C++11 version of the `boost` features you used in your code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class B {
public:
    // T == double -> this ctor can be used
    template<typename U = T, class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<U, double>::value>::type>
    B(int arg1, double arg2) {}

    // Default ctor, available to every class.
    B() {}
};

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    B<double> b_double( 6, 6 );
    B<int> b_int;

    // This line fails
    //B<int> b_fails(6, 6);
}
```

Comment: Can I just replace std:: with boost:: if I'm not using C++11?

Comment: No, since, as I mentioned in my answer, default function template arguments are a C++11 feature. So the only way to make the code above work is by using that feature. I mean, you can use boost::enable_if, but you'll still need C++11.

Comment: I wish I could give you +100. I spent hours looking for a way to get this working and here it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use SFIANE in this case, because it works only if substitution of *function* template argument flails, not when substitution of *class* template argument fails.

What you need is *specialization*.

But as I understand, you should copy implementation of common case in your `double` case, but only add new constructor.

In this case I suggest I little wired technique: You can derive from common case in your specialization.

Then you face 2 problems:

1. You should still have `double` specialized common case to derive
2. You should not call common case default constructor, but some specialized.

There we go:

```
template<typename T, bool = false>
class B
{
public:
    B() { std::cout << "B common\n"; }
    void yahoo() { std::cout << "yahoo!\n"; }

protected:
    struct internal_t;
    B(internal_t*){}

};

template <>
struct B<double, false>: public B<double, true>
{
    B(int, int):B<double, true>(0) { std::cout << "B double\n"; }
};

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    B<int> ib;
    B<double> b(2,5);

    ib.yahoo();
    b.yahoo();
}
```

Comment: Why did you use struct here and not class?

Comment: @user1504193, It doesn't matter actually, whether you use `struct` or `class`. I used struct because it allows omit `public:`, due to all members are public by default in `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

```
B(int arg1=0, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_same<T, double>::value>=0);
```

You forgot the second argument to `boost::enable_if_c` which specifies the type, you forgot the `::type`, and you forgot a parameter name.

If you want something along the lines of `B(int arg1=0, int arg2=0)`, use

```
B(int arg1=0,
  typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::is_same<T, double>::value, int>::type arg2=0);
```

Even better, don't use the underscore c version of enable if. Just use enable if:

```
B(int arg1=0,
  typename boost::enable_if<boost::is_same<T, double>, int>::type arg2=0);
```